# Shiny in R: How can I fade-out my plotOutput from renderPlot if certain conditions are not met?

Tags: r, shiny

the question is straight forward. First, I tried an if-else condition within the render plot. Something like

```
if (input$Next > 0) {
   plot(...)
}
else {
   return()
}
```

This didn't work. The grey area at which the plot would be placed later was shown even though the condition wasn't met yet.
In a next step, I tried to use validate (see  [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/validate.html)). I basically copied the code from the given example. However, it still shows the grey area when the condition is actually not met. My current attempt looks as follows:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
   sidebarPanel(
      plotOutput("test"),
      actionButton("Next", "Next")
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderPlot({
     validate(
        need(input$Next > 0)
     )
     pt <- plot(input$Next,2)
     print(pt)
  })
}
})
```

The plot function is just for illustration. Mine looks different. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: This code works only iIf I remove the inner function `function(input, output)` which is redundant. I then see the `sidebarPanel` that is grey by default and it contains an invisible `plotOutput` (condition is not met yet) and a button. What do you want exactly? Do you want initially only the button (no space reserved for the invisible plot) and if it is pressed then the `plotOutput` should fade in?

Comment: @ UnnamedUser 8. Thank you very much for the comment. This is actually exactly what I want!

Comment: OK, there are few ways to do that. I'll post some solutions in few hours when I have free time.

Comment: @  UnnamedUser. That's very generous of you! Thank you very much. I'm looking forward to your inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **First possibility** - [`conditionalPanel`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/conditionalpanel-demo.html)

We want to show the `plotOutput` if the `actionButton` was pressed. More specifically, if `input.Next > 0`. This condition is evaluated in `javaScript`, hence we have a slightly different syntax - instead of `$` we use `.` after input and we use the parentheses.

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.Next * 1 > 0",
      plotOutput("test")  
    )
```

However, it is quite strange that we multiply `input.Next` by one. It is necessary because `input.Next`, expect a number, returns also attributes. It seems that JavaScript doesn't know how to deal with this...but the multiplication does the trick.

```
[1] 0
attr(,"class")
[1] "integer"                "shinyActionButtonValue"
```

---

In this example the `plotOutput` appears **immediately**...definitely **too fast**.

```
library(shiny)

ui1 <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.Next * 1 > 0",
      plotOutput("test")  
    ),
    actionButton("Next", "Next")
  )
))


server1 <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$test <- renderPlot({
    pt <- plot(input$Next, 2)
    print(input$Next)
    print(pt)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui1, server1)
```

---

2. ["Slowing down the train"](https://youtu.be/Qih-nCjjGaY?t=16s)

In this example, we're going to "slow down" the speeding `plotOutput`. To do so we need the package `shinyjs`.

First, we're going to wrap the `conditionalPanel` into a `div` with an id, say, `animation`

```
div(id = "animation",
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.Next * 1 > 0",
        plotOutput("test")  
      )
    )
```

Then, on the server side, we're going to define the animation in the following way: conditional on the input$next the div should show up with the slide animation.

```
observe({
        toggle(id = "animation", anim = TRUE, animType = "slide",
              time = 0.5, condition = input$Next > 0)
      })
```

Full example:

```
ui2 <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # we need to include this function in order to use shinyjs functions
  useShinyjs(), 

  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("Next", "Next"), 

    div(id = "animation",
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.Next * 1 > 0",
          plotOutput("test"),
          sliderInput("manipulate", "slider", min = 0, max = 1, value = 1)
        )
    )
  )
))


server2 <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Introduce gently the div with an id = "animation" and its all content.
  observe({
    toggle(id = "animation", anim = TRUE, animType = "slide",
           time = 0.5, condition = input$Next > 0)
  })
  # We could animate only the plotOutput with "toogle(id = test")" 
  # - it would work as well, but for the first time the plot is shown
  # way we would get an errors with margins.


  output$test <- renderPlot({
    #plot(input$Next, 2)
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) + geom_bar(alpha = input$manipulate)

  })
})

shinyApp(ui2, server2)
```

---

3. `renderUI`

As you pointed out, the another possibility is to use the function `renderUI`. If you want to render more than one element at once, you have to wrap them into a `list` as in the example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui3 <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("dynamic"),
    actionButton("Next", "Next")
  )
))


server3 <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$dynamic <- renderUI({
    if (input$Next > 0) {
      # if we want to render more element, we need the list
      list(
        plotOutput("test"),
        sliderInput("manipulate", "slider", min = 0, max = 1, value = 1)
      )
    }
  })


  output$test <- renderPlot({
    #plot(input$Next, 2)
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) + geom_bar(alpha = input$manipulate)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui3, server3)
```

Comment: Well, it seems that the multiplication `input.Next * 1` is unnecessary...anyway :D

Comment: @ UnnamedUser. Thank you very much for your extensive answer! It's very nice to have an example of how to delay the plotOutput. This really solves the problem I had. However, I noticed that I want to also have some slider input, which should affect the plot. To be precise, I want to have a barplot, which changes as the slider handle is moved. I'm not sure if a conditional panel is the right choice then because it delays the entire process, which isn't nice. I tried to include the plot into the renderUI that produces the slider but that doesn't work.

Comment: So, you doesn't care about the animation and want the plot to appear with a slider at the same time? (using renderUI function) We can think about :D

Comment: I wouldn't say I don't care ;-) But it's not top priority. I managed this morning to run the plot using this validate function I mentioned in my question. It works very smoothly. However, the grey area (space reserved for plot) is still shown (as was to be expected).

Comment: Ok, I've updated the post :) If you want to render more than element at once, you have to wrap them into a list

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for all the effort you put in :-)

Comment: It was my pleasure :) By the way, I changed the version with the conditional panel too. If you rendered the slider with the renderUI and the plotOutput with conditional panel, it is possible that they were rendered not at the same time. Now, they show up together and  you can always speed up the animation too. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional panel like so:

```
library(shiny)
ui =fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.Next>0",
    plotOutput("test")),
    actionButton("Next", "Next")
  ))

server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$test <- renderPlot({

        req(input$Next > 0)

      pt <- plot(input$Next,2)
      print(pt)
    })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```